# does the javascript date object use the system clock?

Tags: javascript

e.g., if you had:

```
var d = new Date();
alert(d.getTime());
```

is it based on the system clock? if i change the time/date on my computer's clock, am i potentially sending erroneous data back to my server?

Comment: I am curious what you think it would have been based off of if not the system clock. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This uses the system time on the client computer where this javascript is executed. So if you change the date/time on the client computer it will send the new value to the server.

Comment: if you don't want to rely on system clock, use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75529987/1243247

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it uses the system time on the client side.

When posting data, you don't need to post the date of the request (which I think it what you are trying to do), just get the current date (server side) when the post request is made and use this as your date.