# How to get time from server in android?

Tags: android, xml, json, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does anyone know of a good JSON time server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486293/does-anyone-know-of-a-good-json-time-server)

Is there any public `json` or `xml` present on server which I can **parse for current time?** I shall use this time for checking the expiration Period of Trial version of my app, I am not using Calendar or Date classes. I am new in Android. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know its not exactly what you ask but you may also get the time from the network provider (the mobile phone network).

Have you tried

```
LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(activity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
long time = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getTime();
```

it returns the time in millis.

So you don't need an internet connection or parsing JSON, XML ...

Hope this helps somehow,

Tobias

Comment: It return java.lang.nullPointerException, whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Utilities Web Service, that when I "ask" by SOAP to the Server, they return to me the Date.

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getDateTime")
public byte[] getDateTime() {
    UtilWS.showIpClient(wsContext);

    String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format,
            Locale.US);
    String data = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    System.out.println("== Date Requisiton: " + data);
    return data.getBytes();
}
```

And in my Client side:

```
byte[] b = CommWS.send(getApplicationContext(), "UtilWS", "getDateTime");
String server_date = new String(b);
```

The CommWS is my class that implements the SOAP communication with the Server.

cya,
Bertan