# How can I get server date and time without failure in android?

Tags: java, android

We are writing an application in android. We are taking server date and time. But sometimes we are getting blank response from server so my android application crashes due to blank. I have handled it in my code. But User can not see server time. I don't want to deal with local device time. Sometimes that cannot be correct.We want date and time from server all time. How can I avoid such unpredictable behavior of API. Suggest another API to get date and time for India server.

Here is sample code which I am using.

```
        String TIME_SERVER = "time-a.nist.gov";   
        NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);           

        TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);

        long returnTime = timeInfo.getMessage().getTransmitTimeStamp().getTime();

        serverDate = new Date(returnTime);
        System.out.println("Time from " + TIME_SERVER + ": " + serverDate);

        SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        Log.e("FORMATED DATE", ""+formatter1.format(serverDate));
```

Is there any other alternate option to get server date and time ( for ISD )?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442192/how-to-use-an-internet-time-server-to-get-the-time)

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278663/how-to-get-time-from-server-in-android